# If string is empty, then assign null

Tags: c#-4.0, string-comparison

Please correct my code:

```
j.PrDateTime = string.Empty(t.PrDT)
    ? "NULL"
    : DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.PrDT, "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`PrDateTime` is nullable in db, `t.PrDT` is a `string` which might be empty.

Comment: use `null` instead of "NULL"

Comment: @Love Yes. One is a null reference and the other is a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
j.PrDateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.PrDT)
    ? (DateTimeOffset?)null
    : DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.PrDT, "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```